# How to make all divs same height, based on text content?

Tags: html, css, list, height

I'm still having trouble with a long-standing problem. To be concise, my site has 3 list items within an unordered list. In my demo the lists are the green boxes. Each list item contains an image and 3 divs (titlebox,locationbox,pricebox). I'm only concerned with titlebox here. My demo site is [here:](http://testsite24.netai.net/public/public.html)

You can see how each titlebox has different lengths of text, which pushes the location/price down. I've colored titlebox to be grey so you can see them. I want **all titlebox heights to match the height of the biggest titlebox.** I've attached a screenshot of what I'd like.

Here's a demo link in CodePen -- can you help tweak it?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azJKYM

The main unordered list item (contains all 3 greenboxes) has CSS:

```
                .list
                    {
                        width: 100%;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        display: -webkit-flex;
                        display: -ms-flexbox;
                        display: flex;
                        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                    }
```

The individual list item (green box) has css:

```
                .list__item
                    {
                       width: 32%;
                       float: left; /* 10 */
                       display: -webkit-flex;
                       display: -ms-flexbox;
                       display: flex;
                       padding-top: 0.625em;
                       padding-bottom: 0.825em;
                       margin-left:1%;
                       margin-right:0%;
                       position:relative;
                       line-height:40px;
                    }
```

and the titlebox has CSS:

```
.titlebox{
    width: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4.2vh;
    font-family: Garamond;
    color: #002000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color:grey;

}
```

Thanks for any help! The screenshot of desired result is below.

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: It fills me with pain to say this, but have you considered using a table? Also I am assuming the image, price, and location are all single line and can never be two line? Their by leaving the only variable height component title?

Comment: Yes, only titlebox will have variable height. As for using tables, I'd rather not, seeing how I feel that I'm only a tweak away from getting the solution I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this cant be done with CSS because these elements are not siblings. If the structure was different you could make set them to `display: table-cell` and they would adjust to each other. The only way I beleive this will work in its current markup is using a little javascript.

You can simply loop through each of these on the page, see if that height is greater than a previous one and at the end set all of them to be the tallest one:

```
var largest = 0; //start with 0

$(".titlebox").each(function(){ //loop through each section
   var findHeight = $(this).height(); //find the height
   if(findHeight > largest){ //see if this height is greater than "largest" height
      largest = findHeight; //if it is greater, set largest height to this one 
   }  
});

$(".titlebox").css({"height":largest+"px"});
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJMYQQ)

**UPDATE**

To find the tallest of a set of three you can first look through the `.titlebox` of *each* parent `ul` and then run the rest of the script:

```
$("ul").each(function(){ //loop through each first

  var largest = 0;

  $(this).find(".titlebox").each(function(){ //find each .titlebox within its parent (rest is the same)
     var findHeight = $(this).height();
     if(findHeight > largest){
        largest = findHeight;
     }  
  });

  $(this).find(".titlebox").css({"height":largest+"px"}); //update all .titlebox inside of this ul

});
```

[**CODEPEN 2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgWBJE)

Comment: That looks perfect! Except that I plan on having more than just 3 boxes. Each *row* will have 3 boxes, but I may have up to 50 rows. So how can I change your code so that if ONE of the THREE titleboxes in a row are longer than the other 2, make the other 2 the same height as it? Meaning the counter must be reset after 3 I'm assuming...

Comment: Clearly your solution works, so I voted it and thank you. But I can't seem to get it to work on my demo site. I've inputted the script just above the closing </head> tag, on line 647 of the source code. Why doesn't it work though? http://www.testsite24.netai.net/public/public.html

Comment: Actually it's above the closing </body> tag at line 718

Comment: you have an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` which means that either your link to jQuery is broken or your code is being defined before your link to jQuery is being called

Comment: Ahh, I needed to reference jQuery source within my header (obviously). Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

*incase your looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution -

if i understood correctly what your trying to accomplish, so the way you allocate the div's causing you problems. i would try to place the headline and the location in the same div, and keep the price out-side of it like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h2>this title wont affect the location position</h2>
        <p>location</p>
    </div>
    <h3>outside the div</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: yellow;
        text-align: center;
    }

 p {
        position: absolute;
        left: 75px;
        top: 135px;
    }

 h3 {
         text-align center;
    }
```

this way no matter what you will place inside the header the div side will stay the same and so is the location position

Comment: But will this then still push the price box down? I simply want the titleboxes to always be the same height as the tallest textbox on that row, despite the amount of text within it.

Comment: in my example if you notice there is no price box...the title wont push the location nor the price...hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this script to

```js
$(document).ready(function()                
  {
      var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.titlebox").map(function ()
      {
          return $(this).height();
      }).get());
     
      $("div.titlebox").css('height',maxHeight );
  }
)
```

Updated Code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPpEKj

Comment: If I go to the codepen link you provided, the grey title boxes are NOT the same height. This doesn't seem like a solution to me

Comment: Updated. Please try now